# 2 SQL запроса в одном разными условиями

Tags: sql

Есть 4 поле:
contract_id,
spec_summ - сумма спецификации,
oplacheno - оплаченная сумма,
spec_status - статус спецификации: отгружена или еще нет

| contract_id | spec_summ | oplacheno | spec_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 75 | 75 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 30 | 0 | 0 |

Нужен запрос выборки, который должен суммировать oplacheno, также суммировать spec_summ при условии где spec_status = 1 сгруппировав по contract_id

То есть такой массив:

| contract_id | spec_summ | oplacheno | spec_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 175 | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | 0 | 1 |

Если пробовать так:

```
SELECT  `contract_id`, 
                SUM(`spec_summ`) `spec_summ`, 
                SUM(`oplacheno`) `oplacheno`
        FROM `specification` WHERE `spec_status`=1 GROUP BY `contract_id`
```

то суммирование поле oplacheno также происходит только там где spec_status=1, а не все оплаченные суммы

Пробовал так, но все равно не выдает нужного результата

```
SELECT  `contract_id`, 
                SUM(`spec_summ`) `spec_summ`, 
                SUM(`oplacheno`) `oplacheno`,
        CASE
            WHEN `spec_status` = 3 THEN SUM(`spec_summ`) 
        END `FieldELSE`
        FROM `specification` GROUP BY `contract_id`
```

Comment: Подзапросом суммируйте oplacheno

Comment: `SELECT  \`contract_id\`, SUM(\`oplacheno\`) AS \`oplacheno\`, SUM(CASE WHEN \`spec_status\`=1 THEN \`spec_summ\` ELSE 0 END) AS \`spec_summ\`,  FROM \`specification\` GROUP BY \`contract_id\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать условие внутри функции SUM для суммирования поля "oplacheno" только там, где "spec_status" равен 1. Вы можете сделать это с помощью функции CASE внутри функции SUM.

```
SELECT
`contract_id`,
SUM(`spec_summ`) AS `spec_summ`,
SUM(CASE WHEN `spec_status` = 1 THEN `oplacheno` ELSE 0 END) AS `oplacheno`
FROM
`specification`
GROUP BY
`contract_id`;
```

Этот запрос сначала суммирует "spec_summ" и группирует по "contract_id", а затем суммирует "oplacheno" только для тех записей, где "spec_status" равен 1.

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Правда мне надо было суммировать spec_summ где spec_status = 1, поменял oplacheno на spec_summ и с вашим запросом все заработал.

Comment: Отлично, рад что смог помочь